# Javascript radio button validation error pops up for less than a second while it should not disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

Alright after reading like 30 examples and also testing them out I finally decided to post my question since all the examples are not working for me.

So I am not a javascript expert but validating a simple radio button shouldn't be to hard, at least that was what I thought.

I am trying to output a nice css error handling when the form is incorrect. Though, for some reason my radio button error pops up for less than a second and then disappears again. The other errors (non-radio) do work though. For this question I'll just post the code bit of the radio button part.

**The HTML:**

```
<div align="left"><form name="myForm" method="post" style="display:inline" onsubmit="return(validate());"> 

<div class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="1">Automatisering
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="2">Software
<div id="Fout" style="display:none" color="white"></div>
</div>

input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form></div>
```

**The validation block:**

```
function validate()
{

    if(document.myForm.automatisering[0].checked != true && document.myForm.automatisering[1].checked != true) 
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'inherit';
     document.getElementById("Fout").setAttribute("title", "Some error message");    
     document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
     return false;
   } 
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'none';
   }

~~~~~Other validation with text, email, phone, etc. that DOES work. All starting with the if and returning false with div displaying like the radio example.

return( true );
}
```

Things i tried (but didn't work - outputs the error for less than a second while it should not disappear):

**1# Based on some fancy for I found**

```
var elem=document.forms['myForm'].elements['automatisering'];
    len=elem.length-1;
    chkvalue='';
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
    {
        if(elem[i].checked)chkvalue=elem[i].value;  
    }
    if(chkvalue=='')
    {
    document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'inherit';
     document.getElementById("Fout").setAttribute("title", "Some error message!");   
     document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
    return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'none';
```

**2# Based on the values (manual given) of the radio's**

```
if(document.myForm.automatisering.value != 1 && document.myForm.automatisering.value != 2) 
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'inherit';
     document.getElementById("Fout").setAttribute("title", "Some error message!");   
     document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
     return false;
   } 
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'none';
   }
```

**3# Based on the array of the radio**

```
if(document.myForm.automatisering[0].checked != true && document.myForm.automatisering[1].checked != true) 
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'inherit';
     document.getElementById("Fout").setAttribute("title", "Some error message!");   
     document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
     return false;
   } 
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'none';
   }
```

All things I've tried result in the same, I get the error message (div) for 0,5 seconds and it immediately disappears. Also tried to remove the display = 'none' on the else but this results in the same issue.

Comment: would you please provide a jsfiddle or jsbin example?

Comment: Where does your validation code display the error message? It's just putting the error message in the `title` attribute, which only displays when you're hovering over the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not valid:

```
document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
```

`document.myForm.automaterising` is a `NodeList`, you can only focus on a specific DOM element. When it gets an error from this statement, it never executes `return false`, so the form gets submitted.

Try changing it to:

```
document.myForm.automatisering[0].focus() ;
```

Comment: This did it! Actually it was pretty obvious after you post it since now it didn't know what to focus.. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it have been obvious from the error message in the Javascript console?

Comment: Was checking its output directly on the web while working in Notepad. But indeed, should check it next time in a console with error handling which can provide me a bit more Intel.

Comment: Yes. The console should be the first place you go, not SO.

Answer (score 0):

It is acutally working for me. I fixed a syntax error in your HTML (`input` missed its opening tag)
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwRXbr

EDIT:

The issue is that obviously the onsubmit method does not stop the `<form>` from being submitted when you return false. You could create a button that checks the values and then calls `document.myForm.submit()` Here is an example for that:
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYxVJy

Here is the working code:
HTML

```
<div align="left">
  <form name="myForm" action="#" style="display:inline" onsubmit="return(validate());"> 
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="1">Automatisering
      <input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="2">Software
      <div id="Fout" style="display:none" color="white">bla</div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.myForm.automatisering[0].checked != true && document.myForm.automatisering[1].checked != true)
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById("Fout").setAttribute("title", "Some error message");
     document.myForm.automatisering.focus() ;
     return false;
   } 
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("Fout").style.display = 'none';
   }

return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show the corrected code here, not just as a link.

Comment: That's probably just a copying error. If it were the real problem, he wouldn't be able to submit the form at all, so there wouldn't be any validation done.